# как запушить значение из инпута в массив

Tags: javascript

у меня есть функция, которая должна пушить в массив значение, которое я ввожу в инпут по клику на кнопку.
мой код выглядит так:

```
function t7() {

  let a7 = []
  let input = document.querySelector(".i-7")

  a7.push(input.value)
  console.log(a7)

}

document.querySelector(".b-7").onclick = t7
```

но у меня значения не добавляются в конец, а перезаписываются в виде строки, то есть получается всегда один элемент массива, который просто изменяется.

Comment: Вы когда вызываете `t7` у вас перезаписывается массив, каждый раз он пустой. Чтобы этого избежать, вынесите `let a7 = []`

Comment: Про замыкания почитай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вынести объявление массива `a7` за пределы функции `t7`, т.к. каждый раз, когда вы вызываете ф-ю `t7` она перезаписывает `a7 = []`